# casual alternative for the word "emit" in the context of energy

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider this hypothetical expression,

> My relative is personification of bad vibes. He is always emitting negative energy.

I am looking for a casual idiomatic alternative for the word "emission".

I generally see it in the scientific context; gas emission, emission of energy from an atom etc.

I want to know how a native person would say it.

Comment: **Gives off** sounds the most natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Giving off" or "giving out" are casual.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker, I would use "giving out negative energy" or "releasing negative energy".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of "casual", then the word "ooze" might be a valid option. You can say someone "oozes negativity".

It's "casual" in that it doesn't sound scientific or clinical at all, but it's somewhat likelier to appear in a book or magazine article than in speech, where it can still be used for emphatic effect.